# How can I use VS2019 Files in VS2022 and vice versa?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

In my school they use VS 2019. I installed the same because that was what was available at the time (community version for me, I think the same for my school).

I had a couple of issues with VS2019 so I uninstalled everything and installed 2022 version instead. I then began to use this for the last 2 weeks but when I tried to open my old files, I couldn't.

I did install framework 3.1 again and the code will enter runtime successfully, but I still can't see the code that I wrote. I don't want to re-install VS2019 because it kept on giving me issues with intellisense which I just couldn't fix.

Is there any way I will be able to open my old 2019 files in 2022? Also, will 2019 be able to open 2022 files?

Comment: Go to the visual studio installer and make sure you have the frameworks and technologies used for the software you did at school. Visual studio is very good at converting code to work on higher versions of it.

Comment: "when I tried to open my old files, I couldn't" - what happened? Did it give you a message that you could [edit] into your question?

Comment: People do need to know more about the "issues" you talked about. Otherwise, the principles like "things should work in both VS2019 and VS2022" won't help you much.

Answer (score 2):

The generic answer to this is mostly yes but maybe no depending on your specifics.  That's not a helpful sentence, so let me explain.

For the most part, Visual Studio solutions and projects are cross-compatible<sup>1</sup>.  This means that if you have a project from one version, you can usually open it in another version without issue.  The major caveat to this is the range of frameworks supported by each VS version may be different.  VS will often be able to open the project, but might not be able to build and run it.

(Because you tagged this with vb.net, I'm limiting this to .NET versions.  The same concepts may apply for other platforms.)

For example, [VS2019 supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/compatibility#-visual-studio-2019-support-for-net-development):

> - .NET version 5 (Visual Studio 16.8 or later)
> - .NET Framework versions 4.8, 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.7, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, and 4.0
> - .NET Core 3.1, 3.0, 2.2, 2.1, and 1.1.

And [VS2022 supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/compatibility#-visual-studio-2022-support-for-net-development):

> - .NET Framework versions 4.8, 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.7, and 4.6.2
> - .NET Core 6.0, 5.0, 3.1, 3.0, 2.2, and 2.1.

Note how VS2022:

- DOES NOT support .NET Framework versions 4.0-4.6.1, or .NET Core 1.1
- DOES support .NET (Core) 6.0 - which VS2019 does not

It is reasonable to expect that the next version of VS will stop supporting some versions while it adds support for new ones again, so this compatibility range will change with each VS release.

<sup>1</sup>: Each different type of project requires a Project System to support it.  Occasionally, these may be dropped out of support like with the frameworks described above, but with the more severe consequence that VS will not be able to open the project at all.  Some examples over time: Silverlight and Windows Phone projects, Setup projects, DNX (early .NET Core) projects, etc.